# ¿Como quitar título por defecto en una ToolBar?

Tags: android, actionbar, toolbar

tengo una aplicación a la cual le hice una ToolBar personalizada y le quité la ActionBar por defecto, mi ToolBar tiene el título alineado en el centro y en la preview de Android Studio aparece como debe pero al instalarla en mi teléfono aparece el título de la app como en la ActionBar y además mi ToolBar. Aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese título hace que como se ve, se recorra el primer elemento de la ToolBar, el título que aparece está en el archivo strings con el nombre "app_name" y si lo borro mi app no tendrá nombre cuando esté instalada, ¿Cómo puedo quitar ese título?

Mi archivo XML de la actividad principal contiene el siguiente código:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    >

</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

El código de la toolbar es:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="@dimen/elevacion_toolbar"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/huella"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/huella"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_huella"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/titulo_main"
    android:textSize="@dimen/titulo"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_favoritos"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFavoritos"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_favoritos"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_favoritos"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_favoritos"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

En mi clase de la actividad principal tengo este código para agregar la ToolBar:

```
Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
```

Y en mi archivo styles puse el tema sin ActionBar con el siguiente código:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

No se qué debo modificar para quitar el título así que espero puedan ayudarme.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obten la instancia y deshabilita el mostrar el titulo, mediante `.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

incluso al tener la instancia podrías eliminar el texto del titulo:

```
  toolbar.setTitle("");
  toolbar.setSubtitle("");
```